# Magento : I Need to Create a vhost to Access New Storeview

Tags: admin, multistore, magento-1.9.2

I created a **website and store**, followed all steps including **changing base url** of **default configuration**.

How do I access my new website/storeview ? 
Do I need to create a vhost in apache, if so what are steps? How do I access it from my PC.
Currently I cant access magento admin panel, this is what I get (mage2 is my magento installation folder in the htdocs)

[image: this is what i get]

Answer (score 0):

For the site to load over localhost, replace your base URL with the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1/mage2/
```

If you want to use the base URL you entered, you'll have to add an entry to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 yourbaseurl.com
```

Answer (score 0):

For admin login not working, there are two possibilities.

1. disable cache from DB or remove var folder from magento root.
2. Check media and skin URL becoz media/skin files not found so it is display like this. You can update it via db only.
3. For setup new store view, You can create new storeview/website via magento subfolder for ex. localhost/magento/newwebsite.

   Don't need to create new host for this.

I hope this will help you.